# Covert /z/x/y.jpg map tiles to something that can be provided using the WMS specification

Tags: wms, tiles

We have generated some maps in our own software solution where the output is a map stored in XYZ tiling format.

```
/zoom/x/y.jpg
```

I got a request if I could provide it in a WMS.  I am wondering if anyone has some experience on how to in shortest amount of time can convert and setup a WMS that can service these images.

The reason is that the map client dont support XYZ and is bound to use normal WMS only.

We would prefer a windows solution but anyhting will do.

Answer (score 3):

You could resort to using Mapproxy. It can read a z/x/y Tile source and provide a range of output services, including WMS. You probably can just use your directory with the tile layout as a cache backend.

- [MapProxy Documentation](http://mapproxy.org/docs/1.6.0/)
- [Tile source (via http) docs](http://mapproxy.org/docs/1.6.0/sources.html#tiles-label)
- [Cache documenation](http://mapproxy.org/docs/1.6.0/caches.html)
- [Services](http://mapproxy.org/docs/1.6.0/services.html)

You can install MapProxy on Windows if you have the right ammount of Python-Foo :), but Linux is easier.